# Animated Heart React package not linked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

I am using the following package, which I have installed to my package.json.

https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-a-react-animated-like-heart-in-seconds-ts1g371m

I am trying to use this package directly, using the following

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Heart from "react-animated-heart";

export default function App() {
  const [isClick, setClick] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Heart isClick={isClick} onClick={() => setClick(!isClick)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am getting the return message on the console:

```
./src/components/JobListing/JobCard.jsx
```

And the following message:
As you can see it's pointing to my src component, when it should be looking for the package in the install.

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-animated-heart' in 'C:\ApplyWithin_repo_file\ApplyWithin\frontend\src\components\JobListing'
```

Does anyone know how to solve

Comment: can you see the "react-animated-heart" when you do `npm ls --depth=1`?

Comment: Hi Alan, it actually doesn't but it is in my package.json. Why is this and how do i fix it

Comment: run `npm install`

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks, it's now in the npm ls, but still returns: Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-animated-heart' in 'C:\ApplyWithin_repo_file\ApplyWithin\frontend\src\components\JobListing'